Getting TypeError: LocalStrategy requires a verify callback from passport-local
I'm teaching myself passport-local strategy and have encountered the error shown below:
C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\Messaging_App\Messaging_App\backend\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:47
  if (!verify) { throw new TypeError('LocalStrategy requires a verify callback'); }
                       ^

TypeError: LocalStrategy requires a verify callback

Here's my app.js:
import express from "express";
import 'dotenv/config'
import cors from "cors";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "./config/passport.js";
import usersRouter from "./routes/usersRoute.js";
import authRouter from "./routes/authRoute.js";
import messageRouter from "./routes/messageRoute.js";
import profileRouter from "./routes/profileRoute.js";
import chatroomRouter from "./routes/chatroomRoute.js";

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(session({ 
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
  resave: false, 
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // ie. 1 day
    secure: true,
  },
}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use("/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/message", messageRouter);
app.use("/profile", profileRouter);
app.use("/chatroom", chatroomRouter);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Express app listening on port ${PORT}!`));

and here's my passport.js:
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy (
        {
            usernameField: "email",
            passwordField: "password",
        },
        async (email, password, done) => {
            try {
                const user = await prisma.user.findFirst(
                    { where: { email: email } },
                );
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect email" });
                }
                const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
                if (!match) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
                }
                return done(null, user);
            } catch (err) {
                console.error("Error during local authentication:", err);
                return done(err);
            }
        }
    )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, { userId: user.id, username: user.username });
});
    
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    try {
        const user = await prisma.user.findFirst(
            { where: { id } },
        );
        done(null, user);
    } catch(err) {
        done(err);
    }
});

export default passport;

Did some googling before posting this and all I've found is that the error arises due to parenthesis placement in the "new LocalStrategy()" but I don't think that's my case here.
Any help is much appreciated.

I can't reproduce this. Are you sure you're not using LocalStrategy somewhere else in your codebase?

@robertklep My goodness you are absolutely correct, it seems I have forgotten to remove the LocalStrategy code from another file when I was trying stuff out earlier, thank you so much!
